# Eigenvalues of sum of two anti-commuting matrices

Tags: matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eigenvalues of sum of anti-commuting matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41755/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-anti-commuting-matrices)

I know two anti-commuting (nxn)-matrices A and B, n -even. I know also that +-a and +-b are real eigenvalues among all eigenvalues of A and B respectively. How to show that the matrix  A+B has also at least two real eigenvalues of the form +-\sqrt{a^2+b^2} ? (I know also that (A+B)(A+B)^t=(A+B)^t(A+B)=(a^2+b^2)I, where I is (nxn)-identity matrix and AA^t=A^tA=a^2I, BB^t=B^tB=b^2I and ^t denotes transposition).

Comment: Please could you edit your original question,
rather than post a second almost identical one.

Comment: Note: I deleted the duplicate, so the banner on the top is spurious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity's sak that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$
and are non-singular.

Let $V_a$ be the $a$-eigenspace of $A$. Then by anti-commutativity,
we find $BV_a\subseteq V_{-a}$ etc. As $A$ and $B^2$ commute then there is
an eigenvector $v\in V_a$ with $B^2v=b^2 v$ for some $v$. If we let
$w=bv+Bv$ then $Bw=bw$ so $b$ is real (assuming $B$ has real eigenvectors).
On the space $W$ spanned by $v$ and $w=b^{-1}Bv$ the linear transformation
$A+B$ has matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
a&b\\\\
b&-a\\\\
\end{array}\right)$$
which has an eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But I don't understand how this: AV_a ⊆ V_a follows from anti-commutativity and how you got this: w=b^{−1}Bv. 
I also don't understand why B^2v=b^2v holds for v\in V_a. Sorry and thank you again. 

Comment: corrected     !